# How to return from jsp view a list of selected items?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to save in my database a list of data from a jsp view.

This is my Entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class Product implements Serializable {

    // others fields...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Category> categories;
```

This is my Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/product", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @CacheEvict(value="productsHome", allEntries=true)
    public ModelAndView save(@Valid Product product, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
```

This is my view:

```
    <form:select path="categories" multiple="true" cssClass="form-control select2">
      <form:options items="${listCategories}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
    </form:select>
```

When I submit the form to the controller, all product attributes are OK except `product.categories`, it is always null.

But when I manually populate the fields in the database, the  component is able to fetch the information correctly, but when I try to post, it's the same result, the field gets null as well.

What do I need to do to have "category" information sent correctly to the controller?

Comment: In your service you can have (for example) : product.setCategories(product.getCategories());  Make sure while trying to view/edit/update you have an entity object against which you are performing that operations. For reference, you can take a look at here (I have users, roles (list populated in jsp multiselect) here) - https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks

Comment: @AjayKumar 
I tried run your project but I can't, I have de message "Project facet Java version 11 is not supported." when tried to add to the Tomcat server.

If you want, you can see the project in https://github.com/pabloharger/e-commerce
view -> WEB-INF/views/admin/product/edit.jsp
model -> com.harger.ecommerce.models - Product.java.
controller -> com.harger.ecommerce.controller - AdminProductController.java.
I altered my code adjusting with yours, but don't work too.

Comment: You can change 11 to 1.8 in the pom file.

Comment: I'm not able to run your project, it just is not finding the server http://localhost:8080/springbootrocks/. It's returning a 404 error

Comment: after running application type this in your browser - http://localhost:8080. Thats it

Comment: accessing localhost:8080 is the tomcat root, I need to access the website context, and in your demo is /springbootrocks but for me is not working, only my other app in the same server.